# Ingress Not Forwarding Trafic to BackEnd Services Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using **nginx Ingress Controller** using image **nginx/nginx-ingress:2.3.0** and I have this **ingress resource**

**ingress.xml**

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: mydev
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: gateway
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: gateway
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.16.0
    helm.sh/chart: chart-1.0.0
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: dev.local
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: myapp
                port:
                  number: 7703
```

**kubectl get svc -n mydev -o wide | grep myapp**

```
myapp          ClusterIP      10.110.26.106    <none>                             7703/TCP            8d      app.kubernetes.io/instance=myapp,app.kubernetes.io/name=myapp
```

**Ingress Controller Logs**

```
I0811 08:16:30.500042       1 event.go:285] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Ingress", Namespace:"devops", Name:"myapp", UID:"f31ae490-6037-4306-ac6c-0f78726a3b2b", APIVersion:"networking.k8s.io/v1", ResourceVersion:"3894223", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'AddedOrUpdated' Configuration for devops/myapp was added or updated
```

**service.yaml**

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: mydev
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.16.0
    helm.sh/chart: chart-1.0.0
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: myapp
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: mydev
spec:
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 7703
      targetPort: http
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: myapp
    app.kubernetes.io/name: myapp
  clusterIP: 10.110.26.106
  clusterIPs:
    - 10.110.26.106
  type: ClusterIP
```

But traffics are not forwarded to my backend service. Can somebody help?

Comment: how do you analyse that its not working? any logs? can you also paste the service manifest? What's the nginx control response code?

Comment: If I go to dev.local nothing happens

Comment: do i have to put namespace in the ingress resource like backend:
              service:
                name: mydev/myapp

@Adii

Comment: so better to check the service first, `kubectl port-forward  svc/myapp 7703: 7703` if it responding, the something DNS resolution , also add the response of `kubectl get ingress`

Comment: so its mean its the ingress that having issue

Comment: ```mydev myapp nginx www.api.devops.dev 10.1.65.93,10.1.65.94,10.1.65.95``` why its showing different domain?

Comment: it should show `dev.local`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247199/discussion-between-adiii-and-navigator).

Answer (score 0):

I Restarted the DNS pods  and check if I port 80 is accessible and it works